# How to convert Torchvision image tensor to base64 directly?

Tags: pytorch, numpy, image-preprocessing, torchvision

I have this code that is supposed to convert an image entry of a Torchvision dataset to a base64 string. To do that, it serializes the tensor from a Torchvision dataset to a string, modifies that string, parses the string as JSON, then as a numpy array, loads that numpy array to an image and finally this image to base64.

This solution uses superfluous parsing and serialization steps, and is therefore probably slower than a more direct solution. Also, it does somehow not work only on sample 9051, which is why I am looking for a more robust solution.

How to do this properly? Can I directly convert an entry from a Torchvision dataset to a PIL image?

```py
def get_image_as_base64_string_from_torchvision_dataset_sample(
    sample: Tensor,
) -> str:
    image_tensor: Tensor = sample[0]
    nested_lists_of_floats_string = \
        remove_suffix(
            string=remove_prefix(
                string=str(image_tensor),
                prefix='tensor(',
            ),
            suffix=')',
        )
    batch_index: int = 0
    image_as_nested_list_of_floats = \
        json.loads(nested_lists_of_floats_string)[batch_index]
    image_as_nested_numpy_array: numpy.ndarray = \
        numpy.asarray(image_as_nested_list_of_floats)
    image_as_nested_numpy_array *= 255
    image: Image.Image = Image.fromarray(image_as_nested_numpy_array)
    image = image.convert("L")
    image_base64: bytes = encode_image_to_base64_bytes(image=image)
    image_base64_string: str = image_base64.decode()

    return image_base64_string
```

Comment: Yes, I am aware that this horrible mess can only be explained by copying too many solutions for the problem at hand from StackOverflow while loosing sight of what actually needs to be done. ;)

Answer (score 1):

I found you can use the [ToPILImage transform](https://pytorch.org/vision/stable/generated/torchvision.transforms.ToPILImage.html) outside of a dataloader:

```py
def get_image_as_base64_string_from_torchvision_dataset_sample(
    sample: Tensor,
) -> str:
    features_index: int = 0
    features: Tensor = sample[features_index]
    features *= 256
    to_pil_image_transform = transforms.ToPILImage()
    image = to_pil_image_transform(features)
    image = image.convert("L")
    image_base64: bytes = encode_image_to_base64_bytes(image=image)
    image_base64_string: str = image_base64.decode()

    return image_base64_string
```

This already avoids the serialization, string modification steps and drops the numpy dependency. I just tried running with this, and it produces results in line with previous runs. So it seems to be functionally identical to me. The speedup for sampling 10000 images is roughly 50 %, so this was worthwhile to me. Also, this works on every dataset entry, so it is in fact more robust.